# Java reflection not working properly

Tags: java, reflection

I have a code like this

```
final Method method = XYZClass.class.getDeclaredMethod(METHOD_NAME, new Class[] {List.class, List.class});
 method.setAccessible(true);
final List<Integer> output = (List<Integer>) method.invoke(METHOD_NAME, new Object[] {inputRecords, foo});
```

inputRecords is a List of object and foo is an object.

I am getting object is not an instance of declaring class.??

Comment: If foo is an Object (i.e. not an instance of List), the method invocation (once fixed with Jon Skeet's advice) will throw an exception.

Comment: Reflection *is* working properly, you are using it wrong, your method.invoke() statement has the wrong first argument.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to invoke the method *on your method name* (i.e. a string). You should be invoking it on a reference to an instance of `XYZClass`:

```
XYZClass xyz = ...;
final List<Integer> output = (List<Integer>) method.invoke(xyz,
                                     new Object[] {inputRecords, foo});
```

If it's a static method, use `null` as the first argument.

Comment: whats xyz in invoke..?and how i can invoke it on a instance of XYZClass....I don't know much about relection..

Comment: @Saurabh: It's a reference to an instance of XYZClass. Fundamentally you're trying to invoke a method declared in XYZClass. If that's an instance method, you've *got* to have an instance of XYZClass... How would you expect it to work otherwise? It would really help if you would explain what you're trying to do - and whether the method you're trying to call is a static method or not.

Comment: I am somehow testing the method whether it works fine or not.

Comment: How can i create an instance of XYZClass ...XYZClass needs some parameters to instantiate and i just need to test a particular method of a class..

Comment: @Saurabh: I'm not sure how you can possibly expect me to know that. That's like saying "I want to know whether String.indexOf works, but I'm not going to tell you what string to call it on." What are you trying to test, exactly? Do you understand why there's fundamentally a problem here?

Comment: final Class<?> c = Class.forName(XYZClass.class.getName()); i am creating an instance of a XYZClass..

Comment: @Saurabh: But if the constructor has parameters, you'll need to specify arguments for those parameters... Note that doing `Class.forName` does *not* create an instance of `XYZClass`. Basically what you've got is equivalent to `c = XYZClass.class;`.